# What is a socket (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, unix, mysqli

I'm using the mysqli class in PHP to connect to MySQL. The class constructor has 6 parameters: host, username, password, dbname, port and socket. I understand all but the last one. What is a socket in this context and why is it optional?

Answer (score 3):

This parameter is used to specify the path of the unix socket. This should only be used when host is **`localhost`** and the socket is not in the default place.

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name **localhost** specially,
>   in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to
>   other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL
>   programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a **Unix socket**
>    **file**.

Comment: Does it have a purpose? Is it unrelevant to Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to a [UNIX socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (also known as "named pipe"), as created by the UNIX command `mkfifo`. MySQL can use either an internet socket (addr:port) or a UNIX socket (on a filesystem) for connections.

Comment: Does it have a purpose? Is it unrelevant to Microsoft Windows?

Comment: a very rough equivalent in windows would be a named pipe.

Comment: Fine, I don't know what that is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe might also help. Basically, it is an alternative for address+port (TCP) connection, and bypasses the networking part of kernel, which makes it faster, but only works on the same machine.